# Various video/audio encodings play with very distorted audio on PC?

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, vlc-media-player

I have found that various video/audio encoding types play with very distorted audio on my PC. Though other types play with no issue. I have taken files which produce the issue and played them on other PCs with the same OS and media player, VLC, with no issue. I have also played them inside VMs on the issue machine, and the issue persists. I have to then assume the issue is hardware based.

The PC is only about a year old. It has a 5820k and a 980Ti in it runnings windows 7. I have had no other issues with the PC itself, so I have to assume there is a hardware setting (most likely in regards to the GPU) which creates the problem. All drivers are up to date.

I have used a tool I found online to inspect three video files which produce the issue and they have the characteristics presented in the image below.

[image]

I'm a software developer by day but I do not have much if any experience with AV encoding so I am not sure how to research this issue any further. Any help with possible tests to find the issue or the issue itself would be greatly appreciated.